# Ответ вечен (,) как мир (: или —) смерть

Tags: сравнительный-оборот, тире-или-двоеточие

Мозг уже завернулся в бантик. «Вечен (,) как мир» — это сравнение, но нужна ли здесь запятая? Какое правило здесь будет корректно употребить?

Ответ вечен (,) как мир — смерть.

Ответ вечен (,) как мир: смерть.

Оба варианта выглядят презентабельно, но для двоеточия у меня меньше обоснований. Если добавить «это» перед «смерть», то тире будет как между существительными подлежащим и сказуемым. Однако эта конструкция «ответ: …» кажется жизнеспособной. Что в данном случае можно использовать?

Comment: Одну фразу, изъятую из текста, трудно обсуждать. Предыдущую дать можете?

Comment: @shampar предыдущая фраза: «Что может в миг поменять тебя и всю твою судьбу раз и навсегда, бесповоротно и безвозвратно?» (дальше речь идёт о потере близких)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ исправлен (поставлена закрывающая оборот запятая).

(1) *Ответ вечен **как мИр**  — смерть.*

(2) *Ответ вЕчен, **как мИр,** — смерть.*

1. Тире обозначает **присоединительную** конструкцию с пояснительным значением: Ответ вечен как мир (какой именно ответ имеется в виду?)  — (это) смерть.
2. Обособление оборота **факультативное**: оборот может обозначать сравнение и обособляться, но может обозначать обстоятельство, тогда он не обособляется.

Выбор авторский и определяется **по ударению**: оно падает только на оборот или  на оборот и сказуемое.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136774/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ вечен как мир: смерть.*

Сказуемое *"вечен как мир"*: сравнение по смыслу сближается с "вечен", как в выражении *"старо как мир"*, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Вторая часть БСП поясняет, конкретизирует содержание первой части: *а именно каков ответ?* (это должна быть) *смерть*. Ставим двоеточие.